# How to turn off shadows in MaskPass?

Tags: three.js

I have a MaskPass that uses separate scene for a picked object. I'd like the object to be lit the same way as in the original scene, preferably without copying all the lights into the second scene and updating their positions as well.

In r65 it was default behavior of the WebGLRenderer and it seems it was considered a bug and removed. Any ideas how to reproduce the original behavior?

(It only occurs when shadowMap is enabled, which I need to have)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. MaskPass.render calls WebGLRenderer.render, which calls ShadowMap.render... so you just have to add a new parameter ('mask' for example) to the renderer call to omit the shadowmap rendering.