# Disable MaskPass Shadows Three.JS

Tags: three.js, mask, shadow

The shadows in my scene get messed up by including a MaskPass (even though there are no shadow casting objects or lights in the scene/cam referenced by the MaskPass).

```
composer.addPass( clearPass );
composer.addPass( renderPass_background );
composer.addPass( maskPass1 ); // this is the problematic line
composer.addPass( renderPass_foreground );
composer.addPass( clearMaskPass );
composer.addPass( outputPass );
```

I believe my problem is related to [How to turn off shadows in MaskPass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34080681/how-to-turn-off-shadows-in-maskpass) (I'd comment on that but don't have the street cred / 50 rep on here). It seems that extra draws shadow draws are triggered and my THREE.ShadowMaterial / shadow quad starts to fill up.

I've already edited the three.js source code a little but we'd ideally like to stick to the vanilla code if possible. Is it possible to resolve shadow map writing in the MaskPass without source code modifications?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this a few weeks ago in our local version of r86. I did that by passing through a noShadows bool/argument to WebGLRenderer which branched the control calls to WebGLShadowMap.render. A recent update to r87, however, brings the issue back since WebGLShadowMap has been extensibly modified.